# Print two types of pdf different design in fastreport5.0 using delphi xe7

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7, fastreport

I want to take or generate a report with two designs,
one must generate a report with text without images and another one with images .
In my dataset I can identify the category ,but I don't know how to show the report in one single click i.e by one button click I must be able to generate the two designs depending upon by dataset values

Answer (score 0):

You can use the OnBeforePrint event of FastReport like:

```
procedure TMyForm.frxMyReportBeforePrint(Sender: TfrxReportComponent);
begin
  if Sender.Name = 'Picture1' then
  begin
    // Check data set field condition - for example:
    if DataSource.DataSet.FieldByName('MyFieldName').AsInteger = 1 then
      Sender.Visible := True
    else
      Sender.Visible := false;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: If you have FR with script support, you may use in the script:
 `procedure Picture1OnBeforePrint(Sender: TfrxComponent); 
 begin
  Picture1.Visible := ...Type your condution here...                                                                                                         
end;`

Comment: @gpi which is practically the same, except that you must have script support :)